# Convergence in probability of a martingale difference sequence

Tags: martingales, probability-limit-theorems

I am trying to prove that $$\sum_0^T \mathbf x_t \varepsilon_t \overset {p}{\rightarrow}  0  $$
In this case $\ \mathbf x_t \varepsilon_t $ is a martingale difference sequence, $\varepsilon_t$ is non-Gaussian but independent identically distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, $T$ is the total number of observations in the model  and  $\mathbf x_t$ and   $\varepsilon_t$ are independent.

I have found a complicated proof which uses mixingales and uniform integrebility. Is there another, simpler way to prove this result?

Comment: Do you have other assumption on $\mathbf x_{t}$? If this is equal to $1$, the result is not true.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that Xt is a stochastic variable.

Comment: Yes, but so is $1$. Maybe we should also have $\mathbf{x}_t$ in some sense.

Comment: I am not sure. This result was obtained from a book and I am just trying to find a simple way to prove it. It doesn't mention anything about $\mathbf x_{t}$ being $1$. Can you explain why this would effect the result please?

Comment: Do you think the law of large numbers can be used to prove this result?

Comment: Maybe. But it is difficult to say anything without further information on $\mathbf x_{t}$. If $  \mathbf x_{t}$, then you have a martingale difference sequence but $\sum_0^T\varepsilon_t$ does not converge to $0$ in probability in general.